# Is it wise to pretend to be Christian to safely travel through the US?

Tags: usa, safety, religion

In this [Economist](http://www.economist.com/blogs/lexington/2009/07/summer_camp_for_the_children_o) blog it is stated:

> In the most religious parts of America, it is tough being a secular teenager. Many of the kids at Camp Quest say that, at school, they either keep quiet about their lack of belief or are teased for it. What they like about Camp Quest is that no one tells them they are going to Hell.

Then there is this epic Top Gear episode ["lethal car decorating"](http://www.metacafe.com/watch/1325466/alabama_rednecks_topgear/), where it appear that it is not safe to just vent an opposing opinion.

I guess Top Gear is mainly comedy, but are there regions in the US, where you better pretend to be a Christian, just to be safe?

Comment: note that your actual question in the text is (slightly) different to your title - one is pretending, one is definition. If you could sync then, it'd be better.

Comment: Am I naive or does this question sound ridiculous only to me?

Comment: @greg121: yes, you seem naive. Have you ever been to US?

Comment: Yes it does *sound* a bit ridiculous, but if you have travelled outside the tourist zones in the US you might find it less surprising that somebody would find the need to ask a ridiculous sounding question like this.

Comment: Are rural areas in the US more religious and less tolerant than rural areas in Europe, such as in Poland or Russia?

Comment: @vartec Indeed, I have not been to the US and that question didn't raise my need to go there :)

Comment: @gerrit: I'd say similar in terms of tolerance, however difference is that in rural US they are armed to their teeth, while Poland is one of the countries with the least firearms per capita. Also murder rate and violent crime rate in US is 5 times higher than in Poland. So in Poland you'd risk getting insulted, not being shot at.

Comment: Top Gear was deliberately trying to provoke a reaction; even if they didn't have a bunch of other people following them around with camera's to record it (been too long since I saw the episode to remember if they used hidden cameras or not); they were so blatant it was obvious they were trying to provoke a dramatic reaction.  As a result what they got were a bunch of people willing to act like idiots in trade for 30 seconds of fame.

Comment: @vartec , merely being of a different religion, or no religion at all, is of little consequence in almost any non-homogeneous setting in America.  If you are planning on attending a KKK rally, or, as a less inflammatory example, Sunday church, there may be a certain expectation of belief or at least adherence to custom of those settings... failure to adhere to custom could be uncomfortable in the case of church, and straight dangerous in the case of a Klan rally.  You are absolutely correct that purposely offending locals in America is a potentially dangerous proposition, regardless of reason.

Comment: An interesting variant of this question would be: *Is it wise to hide homosexuality to travel safely through the US/Poland/Russia/Uganda/...?*

Comment: To add to the conversation, Freakonomics recently did an episode where people were faking their religion in the southern states to fit in.  http://www.freakonomics.com/2010/04/13/freakonomics-radio-faking-it/  ... I think it's about 6 minutes in.

Comment: @LJ2: which isn't much different from the case in Poland (except there is no KKK). What I'm saying, that consequences are lot less likely to be lethal or even physically violent

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to need to pretend to be Christian while visiting the US.  The US doesn't have an official religion and is a very diverse nation where people travel often.  It is also a very large nation, and unfortunately some people do commit crimes against people for their religion/lack of religion.  This is like any other diverse nation.  There's no issue with being a secular teenager in America, unless you actively argue with those who have different beliefs than yours.  (And if you do actively argue, you don't typically have threats of violence or anything; its just the people of the majority belief may not want to be friends with you).

In the United States in [2009](http://www2.fbi.gov/ucr/hc2009/incidents.html), a nation of 300+ million people had 1376 hate crimes with a religious bias; the majority being anti-Jewish (70%), anti-Islamic (9.3%).  Only 0.7% were anti-atheism/agnostic.  Also, while I couldn't find data that broke down by victim-group by type of crime (so this also includes hate crimes committed against other races, sexual orientations), a large majority of the hate crimes are vandalism/property-destruction/intimidation (63%) and adding in simple assault (assault without intent of injury) and other property crimes you cover (~90%) of hate crimes.  The other 10% is mostly aggravated assault with the addition of about 17 (0.2%) that were murders or rapes; and many of these are possibly based on racial or sexual orientation motivation.  Note the number of [Hate Crimes in Great Britain](http://www.homeoffice.gov.uk/crime/hate-crime/) is similar (1621 religion hate crimes), despite having 1/5th the population of the US.

When meeting strangers it is best not to deliberately insult/mock/convert them from their own religious/political/other beliefs--this is regardless of where you are traveling.  People often get upset when their beliefs are mocked, but again this turning into assault or worse is extremely rare.  However, if your waitress says "God Bless" or something and you mock her for believing in an imaginary being in the sky (rather than just ignore it), I wouldn't be surprised if you get worse service.  Also, note only about ~20% of Americans actually go to church/synogogue/mosque every week, though ~40% will report [weekly attendance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_attendance#Participation_statistics).  While politicians do pay lip service to God/Christianity in US politics more than in some other nations (e.g., European nations), its mostly playing politics.  When [surveyed on religion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_the_United_States#Religions_of_American_adults) about 75% of Americans self-identify as Christian (25% Catholic, 16% Baptist, 8% Methodist, ...), about 5% are Jewish or Buddhist or Muslim or other religion, 15% reply no religion, and 5% refuse to answer.

Comment: great detail in the answer, +1!  It'd be nice to have a link for the stats in the final paragraph though, if you have one.

Comment: @MarkMayo - Added links for citations left out.  (Both wikipedia).

Comment: @drjimbob - great, thanks! Welcome to the site, btw, look forward to more great answers like this from you!

Comment: "There's no issue with being a secular teenager in America" can you please remove this irrelevant and IMO very wrong sentence :/

Comment: @djechlin - It was relevant as the question quoted a blog describing being a secular teenager in America.  About [20% of American teenagers will openly tell pollsters they do not believe in God](http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/us-teens-more-likely-than-adults-to-believe-in-god-heaven-and-angels-250024221.html); this isn't some insignificant oppressed minority.  Religious freedoms are protected by law.  Yes, some ignorant people may harass, or tease or try to convert you if you don't share their locally dominant religious view (which isn't always Christian).

Comment: Yes, there's tribalism where a group makes fun of anyone who is different from them.  It's really not different from being made fun of if you root for the rival sports team from a different area or don't care about sports (and again you won't really have issues with that).  And I've been in places like physics grad school where the majority viewpoint was atheist/agnostic and my fundamentalist Christian roommate was teased about his views being inconsistent with the science he studied.  No threats of going to hell, but again I wouldn't say you'd have issues being religious and a scientist.

Answer (score 22):

As @MarkMayo pointed out there is no official religion.  As the person who had lived in Indiana (a pretty religious state though not part of the Bible Belt) the issue at hand is actually disrespect rather than religious affiliation.

That actually was the whole point of the Top Gear episode you have linked.

One of the few occasions you might have to pretend to be Christian would be a [KKK Rally](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ku_Klux_Klan).

In most rural areas of the Bible belt if you are polite and respectful no one would care what is your religious affiliation or if you have any.

There are areas where you might be treated with extreme suspicion but this doesn't have to do with religion, but rather [blood relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatfield-McCoy_feud).

Comment: Agreed. Don't wear anti-Christian T-shirts. Don't have loud conversations in restaurants about how stupid Christians are. Don't drive round town playing heavy metal on Sunday morning. Oh, and don't go to KKK rallies.

Comment: @DJClayworth : well this is a good advice for all religions/world-views/ethnicities. If you don't purposefully insult them and their culture, they leave you alone. Maybe with the exception of a civil war or revolt, but in that case you have to really ask yourself the question whether you want to travel there.

Comment: @DJClayworth i'm curious why you provide that advice. wearing an anti-christian shirt might get you some weird looks at restaurants, but i absolutely don't think you would be in any danger, and it's certainly not illegal. do whatever you want in the us. by and large, no one cares.

Comment: @sgroves I take it you've been everywhere in the United States?

Comment: @sgroves I did not say that wearing anti-Christian T-shirts would be dangerous or illegal. I said it would be disrespectful.

Comment: @karlson pretty much, yeah. i've been all over the us.

Comment: @sgroves While it may not be illegal your personal safety in the backwaters of the Bible belt isn't guaranteed if you do.

Comment: @karlson very much agreed, but that's true in any country and is just common sense. *in general*, this isn't something you have to worry about in the US. basically, i don't like misleading foreign nationals into thinking the us is scarier than it is (i.e. no scarier than their home country). "don't wear anti-christian t-shirts" is not advice i would give. you can do that in 99% of places in the US without having to worry. the vast majority of tourists are not going to go to the "backwaters of the bible" belt, they'd go to a city in the south, which are like cities anywhere in the US.

Comment: @sgroves I would not make such a generalization for 1 and 2 people who visit the US don't necessarily stick to the cities as evidenced on quite a few questions on this site.

Answer (score 17):

General recommendation when traveling **anywhere** is to avoid discussing any controversial subjects with locals. This include religion, politics, minorities rights, etc. Always divert conversation away from these subjects. If you're a tourist you're there to see, not to make a statement.

Also discussing other subjects, don't try to be smartass about local customs. You might for example despise NASCAR or handegg (aka American football), but you won't win any friends by trying to convince locals that F1 is true racing and soccer is true football.

This doesn't, however, mean that you need to pretend to be a follower.

Comment: Also, don't refer to American football as "handegg" and you'll be just fine. ;-)

Answer (score 16):

In general, no, you do not need to pretend.  Just be respectful.

There's no check at the border, nobody questions you.  There's [no official state religion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_in_the_United_States), and the whole "Freedom of religion" thing is huge there.

Of course, wherever you go - in any country, there's going to be people who discriminate.

For the most part, however - most people, in every country, are more curious than judgmental.

Comment: Saying there's no official state religion really understates the truth.  The first amendment states that "Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof". This is normally referred to as the "separation of church and state" and basically means that the Government can't/will not ever act in any specific way for/against any specific religion. ("Cults" and similar things being the exceptions)

Answer (score 11):

There are situations where for social acceptance pretending to be of the right faith matters but that's all.  It's not a safety issue other than in extreme cases (such as the KKK rally Karlson mentioned.  I would **NOT** recommend shouting "Allah akbar" in a KKK rally--but I would suggest staying away in the first place anyway.)

Comment: I would not recommend shouting "Allah akbar" at meetings by certain European political groups either.

Comment: @gerrit: OTOH, Islam is currently number one religion in quite a lot of Western European countries :-P

Comment: @vartec No, it is not the number one religion by any means in any western European country. On the other hand, insulting Islam loudly can certainly put one in a risk zone.

Comment: I have zero experience with the KKK, so maybe I could be wrong. I haven't heard any stories of violence at one of their rallies in recent memory, other than from people protesting them. Thus, I would guess that you could shout your favorite religion of choice's slogan and the worst that will happen to you is being rudely asked to leave and  escorted out if you dont. There is absolutely no reason to pretend to be anything you aren't, in any public place in the US. Just be aware that antagonizing someone may get undesirable results, but that isn't a problem with a country it's a problem with u.

Comment: However, I should add that there are certainly neighborhoods in the US that you shouldn't go; regardless of who you are, because they are high crime areas.

Comment: I've read a few articles saying that the KKK regard Muslims as the enemy of an enemy (Jews). (Though I wouldn't recommend shouting Allah akbar unless you checked more thoroughly, I'm just going off memory)

Answer (score 4):

Having traveled extensively throughout the U.S., I can say that overall it is a very safe place to visit, regardless of your religion. There are isolated incidents of issues, but statistically it's pretty small.

**Freedom of Religion and Respect**

"Freedom of religion" is an important cornerstone of the U.S., and most of the U.S. is very tolerant of other religions (assuming you are respectful of their beliefs).

Most people would be curious, rather than hateful.

**Don't Offend the Natives**

If you say offensive things about Christianity or Americans, that is a different story. When visiting any country, it is best to not offend the natives.

**Most Non-European Foreigners are Assumed to be Non-Christians**

Unless you are European, pretending probably would draw more attention to yourself, rather than less. Americans tend to assume that non-Americans and non-Europeans are not Christians, and might be surprised if you claim you are one.

A friend of mine from China is Christian, and some of the Americans I introduced her to were actually surprised she was Christian. They assumed she was Buddhist or something else. These same people also didn't realize that most Filipinos are Catholic.

So there really is no need to pretend to be Christian. Unless you're European or American, it is assumed you aren't one.

**Avoiding Being Converted / Proselytization**

The biggest issue some people have with openly not being Christian, is that some Christians will try to convert you. So pretending to be Christian will sometimes get them to back off. This is why many Americans pretend to be Christian, when they never really even go to church and are much more secular in nature.

**Secular Society**

The U.S. has a very secular society, that does not hinge on your religious views. Specific communities might be more religious than others, but overall, the economy and government policies are all secular. This usually creates a divide where people are secular in their daily business and in the workplace, but religious in their free time and at church.

Instead of pretending to be Christian, it might be better to just stay off the topic, and keep things secular.

**Isolated Communities**

There are isolated communities that don't take kindly to strangers (of any kind). Usually those are small backwoods towns that most tourists would never find themselves in. The issue in those towns is that you are a stranger, and being Christian wouldn't necessarily help you in that situation. They'd find something else to be annoyed at.

**Overall**

In most cases, there is no need to pretend. You may find yourself in situations where its best to keep your mouth shut and blend in, but that is true in any country, whether born there or not.

As long as you respect others, and stay out of bad neighborhoods, you will probably be fine, regardless of what religion you are.

Comment: Perhaps you mean "most non-European foreigners are assumed not to be Christian."

Comment: I mentioned that in the body of the paragraph, but didn't put that in the section title. I updated the section title so that the article is more skimmable.